# How to navigate SPC commands with Vim cursor?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil, cursor

I am very used to Vim keys BUT I love to use Emacs. That's why Spacemacs in Evil mode is perfect for me. There is one thing I still cannot figure out how to do. I don't know how to use `h,j,k,l` for navigation in the SPC (M-x) prompt.

It is very awkward for me to use the cursor keys on my keyboard because they are very out of reach. So I am looking for a way to omit them completly when using Spacemacs and Evil mode.

One other thing is to select an autocomplete suggestion. Also here I need to use cursor keys because Vim cursor won't work. If you have an idea to fix this, too - please let me know!

Comment: You can use `C-j` and `C-k` for navigating helm completions buffers. Use `C-h` to go up a directory when in `SPC f f` or similar completions. And learn using `C-a`, `C-e`, `C-f`, `C-b`, `M-f` and `M-b` for the minibuffer as it doesn't support `evil-mode`.

Comment: Ah you are a legend! thanks